# ios input text icon bug

Tags: html, ios

I have an search input field and a 'X' icon on the right side.
When I click the icon on iOS (safari or chrome), I get the text cursor and no event is triggered. I really don't know why the icon behaves in this way.

```
<div class="search__container">
  <form class="search__form">
    <input type='text' placeholder="text" class='search__input' data-action="search" />
    <i class="search__icon-close"></i>
  </form>
 <div class="search__results"><ul></ul></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anybody experienced the same behavior, I found that using the jQuery click event handler was generating the issue.

Adding a touchstart event to the event handler, fixed the issue.
So, instead of

```
$search.on('click'
```

now I have

```
$search.on('click touchstart'
```

Honestly, I don't know the reason.

Hope that could be helpful!